# Count number of possible passwords with given constraints

Tags: c, mpi, combinatorics

I just need some ideas to get started on this. I'm to write a program in C that counts the number of all possible passwords using the digits 0 - 9 along with some other given constraints such as:

1) Leftmost digit cannot be the same as rightmost digit

2) No two digits can appear more than twice in the pw (123242 is not valid)

3) No consecutive digits of the same value (1221 not valid)

4) 4 digits in length minimum

In addition to this, users input via command line arguments the length of the password along with an optional argument of which digit cannot be used.

What's the best approach towards doing so? My idea was to just create a large set of all possibilities without the constraints and begin searching within the set for any pw that conflicts with any of the contraints, removing them. After doing so, I count the elements within the set. I don't know how efficient that is though.

My other question is whether it is much different for me to create this as a mpi program rather than just sequential program.

Comment: @WeatherVane that would be determined by the user via command line argument

Comment: @EugeneSh. I realized perhaps that that idea isn't particularly great since you implied yourself there might be way too many possibilities, but that's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: Better to calculate than count.  Should be just combinations and permutations.

Comment: *"certain digits that can't be used"* aaargh is the "lucky" number `7` banned as being too obvious in a password?  How many different numbers do you have in use? 9? 2? Or only 1 ;)

Comment: @WeatherVane edited for more  details

Comment: Do you need to know the *exact* number of valid permutions, or just if the rules are too restrictive? If the password might have so many digits that calculating all the possibilities will take years, I suggest brute-forcing the results for 4, 5, 6 digits, and project that forward to get an assessment.

Answer (score 0):

Usually dynamic programming works for such tasks. Though you haven't provided the specifics, thus it's not clear whether DP will work in your case too.
In the essence DP is designing a function and calculating its values with memorization. The function will look like `F(n,d)=F(n-1,d1)+...+F(n-1,dK)` or more complex (more variables) depending on your task. Here `n` is the current length of the password, `d` is the last digit, and `d1...dK` are the possible previous digits.

I've given some hints for you:

1. Dynamic programming
2. Memorization
3. Looking at the last digit and the possible preceding digits

You can study more at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) or more reader-friendly tutorials ([TopCoder](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/dynamic-programming-from-novice-to-advanced/)?)

EDIT: one more tip is to use GPGPU - CUDA or OpenCL - together with or instead of MPI.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I added enough details for there to be suggestions, but didn't want to add too much to have people think I want to be spoon fed. Also, in the end, I am required to use MPI for this.

Comment: @trungnt , Stackoverflow is a "spoon-feeding" website (and it's not bad): either you provide enough details for a concrete solution, or they close your question.

Answer (score 0):

It is not so large set that can't be counted by brute-force. Note that it is not needed to check all possibilities, just passwords with 'increasing' digits. It means passwords where digit `d` can't be on position `i` if digit `d-1` isn't on some position `j<i`. Valid increasing digit passwords per lengths:

- 1 : 0,
- 2 : 01,
- 3 : 010, 012,
- 4 : 0101, 0102, 0120, 0121, 0123.

From one increasing digit password it is possible to create [`nPk`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) different passwords, where `n` is number of possible digits, and `k` is number of used digits in increasing digit password.

Here is python implementation of this approach.

```
import math
import time

_ps = {}
def _P(n, k):
    if (n, k) not in _ps:
        _ps[(n, k)] = math.factorial(n) // math.factorial(n-k)
    return _ps[(n, k)]

def _cc(length, last_digit, largest_digit, digits_left, counts, max_digit, max_length):
    counts[length] += _P(max_digit+1, largest_digit+1)
    if length < max_length:
        for d in xrange(largest_digit+1):              # Check digits 0-largest_digit
            if d != last_digit and digits_left[d] > 0:
                digits_left[d] -= 1
                _cc(length+1, d, largest_digit, digits_left, counts, max_digit, max_length)
                digits_left[d] += 1
        if largest_digit < max_digit:
            largest_digit += 1
            digits_left[largest_digit] -= 1
            _cc(length+1, largest_digit, largest_digit, digits_left, counts, max_digit, max_length)
            digits_left[largest_digit] += 1

def count_combs(max_digit, max_length, min_length=4):
    time1 = time.time()
    digits_left = [1] + [2] * max_digit  # Max 2 same digits to use
    counts = [0] * (max_length + 1)
    _cc(1, 0, 0, digits_left, counts, max_digit, max_length)
    s = 0
    for d, count in enumerate(counts[min_length:]):
        print d+min_length, count
        s += count
    print 'Sum', s
    print 'Time: %0.3f ms' % ((time.time()-time1)*1000.0,)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    count_combs(int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]))
```

For largest case it runs ~11min on my laptop. C implementation would be much faster. Usage is:

```
python <script> <max_digit> <max_password_length>
python <script> 6 20
python <script> 9 20  # The largest example
```

Result of the largest case is:

```
4 7290
5 64800
6 563040
7 4742640
8 38435040
9 297410400
10 2179668960
11 14994201600
12 95817708000
13 561778761600
14 2975712163200
15 13959599875200
16 56450035555200
17 189212904115200
18 494001259315200
19 896042510496000
20 851371260364800
Sum 2504688393448170
Time: 648185.829 ms
```